# Probability of an event occuring $10$ times out of $14$

Tags: probability

Ouch, seems like I have been out of school / math for quite some time...

I have a (I assume) relatively easy thing to solve but I fail:
Probability of a rainy day is $25%$. What is the probability that $10$ days from the upcoming two weeks will be rainy?

Now the chance of rainy day is $1/4$ and the chance of sunny/any_other day is $3/4$. Would the result be:
$(1/4)^{10} \cdot (3/4)^4$ ? That seems like awfully few...

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Exactly ten, or at least ten?

Comment: @BrianTung exactly 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need to remember, that any of the $10$ days can be the rainy ones, and then that the remaining $4$ days are the sunny ones.

In the expression $(1/4)^{10}(3/4)^4$, you assume that some *specific* $10$ days are rainy (perhaps the first $10$ of them).

You need to multiply the probability with the number of ways that you can choose $10$ rainy days out of $14$ days. This is also knows as the binomial coefficient, and you denote it by $\binom{14}{10}$. Thus, the probability you are looking for is

$$\binom{14}{10}(1/4)^{10}(3/4)^4.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: How many ways can you choose $10$ out of $14$ days?

Comment: In your question, you gave the correct probability of there being $10$ rainy days and $4$ sunny days. Now, this corresponds to one choice of $10$ out of $14$ days. You need to multiply your probability by the number of ways you can choose $10$ days out of $14$.

Comment: All clear, thanks a lot for the explanation, will upvote.